# Why does the program run only when it is in the default folder of IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So recently I was bombarded with the below error.

I have a very bad understanding of Java and how the internal memory location and file compiling work. So, when I ran my program(every program gave me the error so I guess it doesn't matter which program I ran and for that matter, I didn't include it here), it started giving me this error. I looked if there were any errors with my classpath and working directory, but still, after applying those too it didn't help much, and I still got the same errors.
The programs ran from the terminal using commands but from the normal "Run" function, it gave me this error.
I just restored the default setting of the IDE and it now works.
The difference I found was that after restoring the default settings, the project location was the default folder- IdeaProjects- whereas when I encountered the error I used to set my own location for the projects. Is it due to this? I had the same kind of problem in eclipse when I set the location of the project outside of the eclipse workspace.

Is the location of the project simply the reason I got the below error and if so why? I just don't understand how the internal mechanism of the whole programming thing works. About the directory, memory allocation, etc. Can anyone provide some decent materials after which I can be at a stage where I can separate what is the error and why is it causing or why the program doesn't run?

Full error:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=57983:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/(myname)/Desktop/Folders/College/2nd sem/CS 2/Labs:projects/Lab3/Lab3dot34.0/out/production/Lab3dot34.0:/Users/(myname)/Desktop/Folders/College/2nd sem/CS 2/Labs:projects/Lab3/Lab3dot34.0 Main
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
```

Initially, I tried to view the working directories and add/change the classpath from the project structures like every suggestion found on the internet but still, the error existed.

Comment: The error is a ClassNotFoundException telling you that the class called Main.java cannot be found at that particular location.  You cannot just move things around in your project folder.  You must use the move tool provided by Idea.

Comment: The Main.java was in my src folder but still, but it still showed the same error, am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I'm not an Idea expert, but in Eclipse, you have to create a separate Run Configuration for each Java project.

Comment: Thank you but should the run configuration always be in the eclipse workspace? I don't know if I am making sense but when I change the workspace it causes error.

Comment: I created one workspace when I installed Eclipse.  I never change my workspace.

Comment: It would help if you could open the java file that you want to run in IDEA and attach a screenshot of the full IDEA window including your folder structure and the error message, which may include any clues about what is wrong. Also, you could click the IDE main menu `Help | Contact Support` to contact the IDEA support team directly and they could help you to investigative this issue.